# Cron job error remains after setup

Tags: cron, magento2.2, magento-2.2.1

I get a problem about cron jobs.

I have followed the tutorial both on 2.0 and 2.2

> http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/config-guide/cli/config-cli-subcommands-cron.html#config-cli-cron-bkg
>
> http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.2/config-guide/cli/config-cli-subcommands-cron.html

And did setup of cron jobs,

[image]

I can ensure the location of the files are correct, because I have double checked many times. But the error **`"One or more indexers are invalid. Make sure your Magento cron job is running."`** remains there. I also clear the cache but it does not work...

Can anyone help me? Thanks for any advises.

Comment: you should include php bin/magento indexer:reindex in cron your too, before running the main cron

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Run these commands into your terminal This will reindex your all files

> php bin/magento indexer:reindex
>
> php bin/magento cache:flush

Check again if still any problem persists.

Thank You!